# microtime() or hrtime() for generating a unique number in a foreach loop

Tags: php, microtime

This has been asked before I think, but with key differences in the details...

So I want to group an array of product sub-arrays by a specific grouping value found in some sub-arrays. The grouping value, however, isn't set for all of them, only for those that are grouped together... This may sound a bit confusing so far, but I promise it'll get clearer when you take a look at the code below... So I'm doing this:

```
            $grouped = array();
            $i = 0;

            foreach ($items as $k => $item) {
                if ($items[$k]['ITEM.GRPCODE']) {
                    $groups[] = $items[$k]['ITEM.GRPCODE'];
                } else {
                    $i++;
                }

                $group = $item['ITEM.GRPCODE'] ? $item['ITEM.GRPCODE'] : md5(microtime());

                $grouped[$group][] = $item;
            }

            echo 'Groups: ' . count(array_unique($groups)) . ' - Single: ' . $i . '<br />';
            echo count($grouped) . '<br /><pre>' . print_r($grouped, true) . '</pre>';
```

At this point I should mention that I already know, for the current dataset, how many are the ones that are grouped together and how many are the single ones (the code I used to calculate each kind is also found in the code above)... So for an unchanged number of Groups/Single of 314/238 (the first `echo`), after a number of page refreshes I noticed that `count($grouped)` (the second `echo`) fluctuated from 552 (the sum of the two numbers above) to other values less than that, like 545, 547, 551, making it obvious that `$group`, when calculated by `md5(microtime())` had produced 2-3 identical values, thus grouping products together that shouldn't be grouped together otherwise... Maybe the loop was so instant that even `microtime()` couldn't handle it? Then after some research I replaced `md5(microtime())` with `md5(hrtime(true))` and this time after A LOT of page refreshes I kept getting 314/238 for the first echo and 552 for the second one, which means that I was getting the expected groups every time...

So what's happening here? Is it that the loop was so instant that `microtime()` couldn't handle it? Is it that `hrtime()` is so more precise than `microtime()`? Is it something else?

Can you please share your thought and shed some light on this? Additionally, if neither `md5(microtime())` nor `md5(hrtime(true))` is the proper way to produce unique numbers in a foreach loop, could you give me another idea on how to do it better? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about simple counter instead of unreliable time? looks like `$i` can be used, so instead of `md5(microtime())` just use `$i` or `('id'.$i)` to avoid possible duplicate numbers

Comment: You could use `uniqid()`.

Comment: @Barmar I already researched using `uniqid()` but according to this post https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#95001 it uses `microtime()` behind the scenes, so why use it?

Comment: @IłyaBursov it has to be something _long_ enough as it'll be used as the products' SKU later in the process...

Comment: @FayeD. `('longstring'.$i)` ? or `str_pad` (btw, there is actually no need in long string, unique is enough for SKU)

Comment: @IłyaBursov is `md5(hrtime(true))` really such a bad idea? I made about 50+ page refreshes so far and I'm still getting constantly 552 groups, meaning that no duplicate timestamps, or md5 collisions occurred... I honestly don't know what's my best route to choose. All I know is I need some unique, _long_ enough strings...

Comment: @FayeD. yes, hrtime is that bad, fact that your computer was not fast enough does not matter

Comment: @IłyaBursov what about `md5('some text seed here' . $i)` then? BTW, I know _long_ isn't needed for an SKU, it's just a personal preference. Uniqueness is another story of course!

Comment: @FayeD. it looks like XY problem, why do you want to implement slower and less robust solution?